# Inhertitance between @Entity and @Embeddable

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa

**Motivation**

My app makes requests to some web service based on contents of table foo. I would like to log those requests (in a data base) as well as value of row of foo, which was used to make them. Still, as data in table foo can change over time, I need to log exact contents of row (rather then its id). I am using Hibernate so I thought, I could embed row of foo in entity representing request. To have clean class hierarchy I would like to have something like this:

```
 class Foo
 {
   /*
    * Here goes some properties of Foo, which specify columns names etc.
    */
 }

 @Embeddable
 class EmbeddableFoo extends Foo
 {
   //EmbeddableFoo should have the same properties as Foo
 }

 @Entity
 class EntityFoo extends Foo
 {
   @Id
   Long getId() { //EntityFoo  has some id }
   //EntityFoo should have the same properties as Foo, except that
   //it has id
 }
```

**Problem**

This will not work, because *EmbeddableFoo* doesn't *see* properties of *Foo*. I can add *@Inheritance* annotation over *Foo*, so that *EntityFoo* *sees* properties of *Foo*, but it will not solve my problems with *EmbeddableFoo*

**Question**

Is there an easy (i.e. not requiring to write a lot of redundant code) way to have *@Embeddable* and @Entity* inherit from the same class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you checked the annotation `@MappedSuperclass` ? that might be what you are looking for.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html

> Designates a class whose mapping information is applied to the
>   entities that inherit from it. A mapped superclass has no separate
>   table defined for it.
>
> A class designated with the MappedSuperclass annotation can be mapped
>   in the same way as an entity except that the mappings will apply only
>   to its subclasses since no table exists for the mapped superclass
>   itself. When applied to the subclasses the inherited mappings will
>   apply in the context of the subclass tables. Mapping information may
>   be overridden in such subclasses by using the AttributeOverride and
>   AssociationOverride annotations or corresponding XML elements.