# can @Entity be also @embeddable

Tags: hibernate, jsf, entity

I have an @Entity, but I would also like to use this entity as a embedded part in another entity. Is it even possible in JSF? I couldn't find any example of that kind of usage of @Embeddable, and neither could I find any materials clearly saying that this is forbidden. That's why I'm asking you guys - Can @Entity be @Embeddable? maybe some materials to read? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At worst, you cannot mix @Entity and @Embeddable annotations on the same class. At best you shouldn't.
(It's a JPA/Hibernate issue, not JSF one.)

You may want to take a look at:

- [A class that behaves like @Entity and @Embeddable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029745/a-class-that-behaves-like-entity-and-embeddable)
- [Should an error be thrown if a class is annotated with @Entity and @Embeddable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021355/should-an-error-be-thrown-if-a-class-is-annotated-with-entity-and-embeddable)
- [Inhertitance between @Entity and @Embeddable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597806/inhertitance-between-entity-and-embeddable)

and check if a @MappedSuperclass is not what you need.

Comment: Thanks, but I already read thos threds - none of them is what I'm looking for. Your answer celared the doubts, so now time to read some documentation and find something that I can use. Thank you for answer.